# Post data from server A to Server B with Form

Tags: django, post, header, http-referer

I am doing a ecommerce project.

When user check out, system will redirect them to payment page(Provide by 3rd party). Show in the diagram.

[image]

The solution that I am using is send a Post Request through form to another server (Payment Server). Show at the Redirect. Payment Server will then let user to continue to fill up the information and post the process data back to the origin server.
I encounter a problem where server B could not detect the Referer and Origin URL of the sender. Which Server B will use the Referer url to check with their IP White List. Error show at Browser.

[image]

I am using a class base view function with template. In the template there is an hidden form with Post method and the url of server at the action field.

When user click submit, it will occur this issues. Anyone has encounter this problem before? Or is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Issues has solved.

The problem is not in the Django or CORS settings at the settings.py. The cause of this is because it does't post the header of referrer. To solve this I just add the snippet below. It will post the data and redirect to the payment server. With Origin and Referer.

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

Reference from this article.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy